# Hlookup across different sheets returned error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am currently trying to lookup value from different sheets and I am having problem getting excel to accept the formula. Would someone kindly enlighten me on this?

**=HLOOKUP(C8,INDIRECT(“’”&G8&”’!$1:$$3”),3,0)**

Thank you in advance!!

Update: the correct formula is as below:

**=HLOOKUP(C9,INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&"$1:$3"),3,0)**

Tried above and it works. G9 refers to the dynamically changing sheet name

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i fully understand what your asking but i do think i know the answer. From my understanding you have something like this:

Sheet1 looks like:

```
     a            b          c
8   Cats        Dogs      Frog
```

Sheet 2  is:

```
    a            b          c
1   Cats        Dogs      Frog
2   red         hot       river
3   blue        cold       hat
```

What you want to return is what is on row 3 for cell c8 (Frog in my example).

To do this if your using microsoft excel your formula should be something like

**=Hlookup(c8,'Sheet 2'!$a$1:$c$3,3,false)**

What this will return is **hat** because it is has found the word frog and then gone 3 rows down to find your information. With excel you dont need the indirect as you can just click through the different sheets.

I hope this helps if not please give me some more details and i will try help answer

Comment: Not really. I wanted to hlookup to multiple sheets in one excel. That is why i need to use indirect function.

Comment: there are probably no less than 30 sheets for me to lookup so I will need indirect function in order to make it work. My problem is similar to the link below:
https://www.xelplus.com/excel-indirect-function/